# ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value

Tags: sql, django, oracle

I created a view that uses `WM_CONCAT` to group results together, like this: `wm_concat(DISTINCT complies)` and it runs smoothly in DB, without any errors.

But when I try to put it in a Django app, using, `models, views, tables` it gives me an error `ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value` .

I tried using `listagg(complies, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY code) complies,` but that gives me a DB error `result of string concatenation is too long`.

I'm aware that `WM_CONCAT` is not supported by Oracle, but I have used that successfully before.

Status in `uwsgi` says `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-22922:`

Is this a DB fix or Django fix, and how do you fix it?

Comment: You must avoid `wm_concat` function because it is undocumented and discovered as workaround at Oracle 8i times. `Django` has nothing to do with `Oracle`. Error is quiet clear, `result of string concatenation is too long` which mean the result of concatenation is more than 4000 chars. You can do a `substr` and select 4k characters

Comment: @XING yes, I had used `wm_concat` successfully before. 
That error, `result of string concatenation is too long` happens when I use `LISTAGG` but not when I use `wm_concat`. It runs without any errors in `PLSQL`, but when I call it from `models` in `Django` it gives me and error:ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value` I don't understand why that is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem! 
I wrapped my whole `SELECT` into another `SELECT` and used `LISTAGG` on those columns that were already using `WM_CONCAT`.

Now the results are displaying without a problem.